# Li-po battery balance charging circuit

Tags: batteries, circuit-analysis, battery-charging, solar-cell, lipo

I work on a solar tracking project and in this project I have to charge my Li-po battery to store power and use this power for supplying the system.

For this problem, I searched for Li-po battery balance charging circuits and I found one. My problem is lack of time (deadline) and I couldn't be sure about this circuit's reliability. Could you give me advice or could you approve my circuit if it is proper?

[image: Li-Po battery balance charger circuit]

Comment: What does your simulation resilts tell you?

Comment: I couldn't see the simulation results since there is no rechargable battery library to add Proteus. I set the circuit in Proteus and I couldn't be sure how can I see the output voltage for the cells. I connected a DC voltmeter and there was a +MAX sign when I start the simulation.

Comment: When I look the general view of the circuit it seems okay, but I will order the components if I will be approved by a person who knows this circuit

Comment: Please provide full details about the battery pack including total capacity, number of cells in series and total number of cells. Please advise what is the Vmpp and Impp of the solar panel. If I had to design a balancer that was guaranteed to work right the first time, I would use an IC from TI or Linear and use the datasheet, reference design, and app notes to guide me.

Comment: No need for a battery pack library. You can get good results using just voltage sources to see the dynamics and trip points and a gigantonormous capacitor is a good analogy to a battery.

Comment: I've designed and built a very similar circuit and it works fine. The idea is that there is a bypass circuit in parallel with each cell. At around 4.2V the TL431 starts sinking current, turning the transistors on allowing charging current to bypass the cell, preventing it from going above 4.2V and allowing the other cells to continue charging. Do note that each bypass transistor will dissipate (4.2V * charging current) of power when it's cell is full. Depending on charge current this can be significant and require heatsinking.